# Detect Object Defects with Open CV

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I try to identify changes on an object. Therefore I take a picture before and after using the object. At the moment I'm working with the **absolute Difference** of the two pictures and taking the **contours of the resulting difference image**. That works fine as long as the object is positioned perfectly and captured like in the image before. Only small differences in its position make my method useless.

Has anybody a different solution approach with OpenCV oder EmguCV? I was thinking about checking if one of the neighbor pixels is identical then there should be no change detected, but I don't know of an existing performant algorithm.

Example Images (Pictures don't match my usecase, but they should be helpful to illustrate my problem):
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOiy.jpg)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O5xQ.jpg)

Comment: Hello, can you please add some details regarding what type of "changes" you are expecting to occur? Coloring? Sizing? Location? Is your image always taken from exactly the same position relative to the object? Is the ambient lighting constant?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I want to detect if my object was damaged and where those damages are. Therefore I take a reference picture of the object and later the after picture. My pictures are always taken from the same position but I recognized that it is almost impossible to reproduce a pixel-precise after image. Ambient lighting is constant.

Comment: Okay so it's a kind of, automated, visual inspection application? Perhaps if you could include some sample images I'll take a look at a solution.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Unfortunatelly I can't include some example images. I'll try take some examples that I can show you. But i guess it won't be before Monday.

Comment: Understood, if the application is confidential perhaps try and provide some faux examples? Some falsified images that you consider to exhibit similar differences.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I added some example pictures. Please let me know if they are not helpful. Then I'll take some others. But it should illustrate my problem that a minor (in the example pictures it is bigger than in reality) movement of the object will make my AbsDiff-method useless.

Comment: How close to the real thing are these? Is it fair to say: You are looking to find imperfections on an otherwise homogeneous, white surface? What will really help if you try to real "boil down" the problem to the simplest form. Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Added new images. They fit better now. I'm looking to find imperfections on an object that **is placed** on an white surface. The object itself **is not homogeneous**. In this example I want to detect that the cover is opened, the white mark on the flash and that the settings wheel was turned. I hope I could clearify the problem now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many way to do this. I like the following:

- Histogram match. Get a histogram before and after and check for differences. Is sensitive to changes in lighting. Very good method if you are in a controlled lighting setting
- Correlation match. If you use MatchTemplate you can get the “quality” of the match. This can be made to be less sensitive to light. But is sensitive to rotation changes between the two images.

Try to implement some and let’s see your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that I want to highlight the areas where the differences are located. Both of your methods are only capable of telling me that there is a difference and not where. Am I right?

Comment: I have used Histogram Match on an array of 10x10 blocks. Here you can tell witch cell is affected. The same block method can be used for Correlation match. I do not think you will get a stable system if yours blocks are too small.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll think we are coming closer to it. But isn't there the same issue as with my used method. Once the object is moved slightly it will spot a difference, because for example a part of the object will be "visible" in a different block than before. So the histogram of the blocks will differ, although there is no change on the object-

Comment: Well, not if you combine them. Template Match to find the object (Rotation and translation) and then place the 10x10 blocks on top (rotated and translated)